# How to debug "Error The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information" in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

After following all the process to fix this in my Ubuntu 14.04 I am not able to fix the issues I followed steps like

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Add the extension in mu php.ini file located in /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

After the all I restart my server by using the command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But still I am facing the same error. I also tried some other process too but my issues were not fixed yet.

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` say? Is `mysqli` listed? Have you checked that mysqli's ini-file is symlinked in `/etc/php/5.6/apaches/conf.d/`? The symlink-target should be something like `/etc/php/5.6/mods-available/mysqli.ini`.

Comment: No mysqli's ini-file is not in both of the directory conf.d and mods-available

Comment: Do you have multiple php versions installed? AFAIK, Ubuntu 14.04 comes tith PHP 5.5 and not 5.6, so if you have multiple versions, php5-mysql might be the 5.5 version and not 5.6.

Comment: yes I had the php 5.5 and I upgrade that to the 5.6 for cakephp 3.4.My current version is PHP 5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 (cli). After the up-gradation i was facing this issues... So what I need to do r8 now... plz suggest

Comment: I also upgraded my mysql version from 5.5 to 5.6. just now, Restart the server but still I am facing the same isssues..

Comment: I'm not an Ubuntu user but... 1) I don't think you're supposed to edit ini files manually, you probably have `/usr/share/php5/mysql/mysqli.ini` already 2) Debian-based distros are heavily customized and you often need to run a command to enable or disable stuff.

Comment: When you install php-extensions through aptitude, most packages (like php5-mysql) automatically gets enabled after install so you never need to enable them through php.ini. If you can't find the `mysqli.ini` file in `mods-available`, then it haven't been properly installed, not for that PHP version anyway.

Comment: Dear Magnus Eriksson, I was installing several times but it's fact that my mysqli.ini is not in mods-available. Before up-gradation from php 5.5 to 5.6 it was working fine but after up-gradation I am facing this issue...